# using css3 to render instead of canvas in fabric.js

Tags: css, fabricjs

Is it technically possible to use CSS3 to render SVG instead of canvas in fabric.js ?
http://ecsspert.com/play/css3-logos/twitter.php#edit

Comment: The website you linked to crashes my browser: Firefox 17.0.1 / Windows 7

Comment: Experiencing the same. Is the link malicious?

Comment: I used chrome on android and on ubuntu linux. The link works fine. you can report your bug to the firefox team.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is technically possible to reproduce SVG shape (or set of shapes) in HTML+CSS.

Basic shapes -- rect, circle, ellipse, line, polyline, polygon -- should be pretty straightforward.

Complex shapes (path) will likely be quite a hassle. How to reproduce bezier curves? With border-radius?

Quick search led me to [this](http://www.janzubko.com/evolution/html_css/css_round_corners.html) but it looks like only a simple experiment.

Comment: I've found a library built on top of Raphael which is called Donatello https://github.com/dnewcome/Donatello

Comment: But Raphael is using SVG, so if Donatello is "on top of it"... does it also use SVG?